# UI chat Screen in Ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making app in which there is a chat window. In this window there is one image and a label on that image in custom cell.

I have take two custom cells, one for sender and other for receiver. Both cell are same with left and right alignment.

I want that when the length of comment is increased then whole comment shows in multiline within that image(increases the image size also) .
how can I handle this situation?
I am using setVariable method to set content on cell. I am trying comment code for framing like below  comment code but it doesn't work

```
  - ( void ) setComment : ( NSString* ) Comment
      {
        [ txtComment setText : Comment ] ;
         /*CGRect frame1 = txtComment.frame;
           frame1.size.height = txtComment.contentSize.height;
           txtComment.frame=frame1;*/
       }
```

Comment: I don't have a precise answer for this, but I've seen approaches where a) (as Pavan notes below) a custom height is defined, and b) the image for the chat bubble is broken up into pieces, with a separate images for the top middle, and bottom, so you can keep adding middle images to make the bubble larger.  Anyway, I'd recommend looking at the source code for JSQMessagesViewController (https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController), which does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use auto layout to define the custom cell height. It will help you create a dynamic cell height depending on the length of the comment. You can read about using dynamic height using auto layout in [this link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout)

Answer (score 0):

To make this done you can do the following:

Subclass UITableViewCell and also create xib file.

Go to the xib file and add UIImageView and UILabel objects to your cell. Also create an outlet for the label.

As Pavan Kotesh mentioned the easiest way is to use auto layout.

Add top space and bottom space constraints to the cell content view for both image view and label. Then set constraints for x position for both subviews and finally set width and height constraints.

Height constraints must be "Greater of equal" type to let you change size of the views.

Having done that in Interface Builder all you need is to add one method to your subclass for setting a message.

```
- (void) setMessage: (NSString*) message
{
    CGFloat oldLabelSize = _label.frame.size.height;

    _label.text = message;
    [_label sizeToFit];

    CGFloat newLabelSize = _label.frame.size.height;

    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height += newLabelSize - oldLabelSize;
    self.frame = frame;
}
```

After calling this method add the cell as subview to you chat view.

EDIT:

I think your -cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation is wrong. What does `[ChatViewCell send]` perform?

I would have done it like this:

First declare two arrays in your table view controller class. The first is for storing the text of messages and the second for storing cell heights. Also you can create some structure to store those values. After user has finished inputing a message you should somehow estimate cell height and put both height and cell's message to the appropriate arrays. After that you should insert new row(section) in your tableview using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method.

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

If dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil you should just initialise new ChatViewCell and after `if (cell == nil)` statement set its message from the appropriate array (due to reuse you should set cell's content every time it goes on screen).

In your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method return values from array that stores cell heights.

Comment: there are one problem on this code when i scroll table view its position get change and label's text break in multiple lines...

Comment: @user3736489 I can only guess that you have some issues implementing UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods. Post your view controller code and it'll be more clear.

Comment: - ( NSInteger ) tableView : ( UITableView* ) tableView numberOfRowsInSection : ( NSInteger ) section
{
  return [commentArray count] ;
}

Comment: - ( UITableViewCell* ) tableView : ( UITableView* ) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : ( NSIndexPath* ) indexPath
{if([[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"user_type"] isEqualToString:@"S"])
  {
  ChatViewCell* cell = [ tblComment dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier : @"send" ] ;
    if (!cell) {
      cell = [ ChatViewCell send ] ;
    }
    [cell setComment:[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"user_comment"]];
    NSString *dateTimeStr =[[commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"comment_date"];
    return cell;
  }